# Python application not loading graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Apress/beg-artificial-intelligence-w-raspberry-pi/master/Chapter%205/tipping.py) Python script the percentage appears in my command line but the graph does not display. I'm running this on the Raspberry Pi. All I've done so far is:

```sh
sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
sudo apt-get install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/scikit-fuzzy/scikit-fuzzy.git
cd scikit-fuzzy/
sudo python setup.py install
cd ..
python tipping.py
```

How do I get it to open?

Comment: You give absolutely no information about your environment. If `plt.show()` doesn't show up a plot, there may be a lot of reasons; please don't force potential answerers  to guess.

Comment: Apologies. Additional info added.

Comment: Ok, Raspberry Pi probably doesn't have a graphical user interface (activated), right? Are you directly logged to it, or via a tunnel?

Comment: I had tried ssh'ing onto the Pi, logging onto it directly and running my program through the desktop interface and I also tried running it on my Mac but nothing worked. In the end I made the change mentioned below to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have first thought about adding he following line to the code:

`plt.show()`

However, it can also be that Python is storing the graph information directly in the memory but not showing it. In this case you must change the "Graph visualization" preferences in Python. If you are running Python through Spyder, then you must go to Tools>Preferences>Graph visualization and tick the option related to show the graph in a different window.

Comment: I added it below easc instance of `plt.tight_layout()` but it made no difference.

Comment: Are you running Python via Spyder?

Comment: No. just running `python tipping.py`